# Command and use the result of it to run another command

Tags: command-line

I want to make `ls` and `cd` to first or second directory it shows, whatever name the first one or the second would be (`dir1` or `dir2`, in this case):

```
$ ls { + some command like | grep which would get me to dir1 or dir2 or any other dir I want to }
dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4
```

Is it possible?

**UPDATE**:

I want to do that in the terminal without creating an external script.

Comment: I think I'm missing something. From your example (four directory names being returned) what do you want to actually happen?

Comment: I got the first or second directory.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking. Are you asking for something to just show you the first two directories?

Comment: Okay so now grep is involved. We're filtering... What's the input and what's the desired output? Why are we selecting "dir1 or dir2"? Because they're first?

Comment: @Oli please look at my answer once. I need your help to fix the final part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ls | head -n 1 && cd "$(ls | head -n 1)"
```

will do the job for first directory. For second directory, use:

```
ls | awk 'NR==2' && cd "$(ls | awk 'NR==2')"
```

For n-th directory, you can use:

```
ls | awk 'NR==n' && cd "$(ls | awk 'NR==n')" #change n with the wished line number.
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do

```
alias cd1='cd "$(printf %s\\n */ | sed q)"'
alias cd2='cd "$(printf %s\\n */ | sed -n 2p\;2q)"'
```

and similar, but you can have problem if there is not one or two sub-directories.

Answer (score 1):

I just made this up:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir_counter=0

for i in *; do
    echo "Checking "$i"";
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then
        echo "$i is a directory"
        let dir_counter=dir_counter+1
        if [[ "$dir_counter" == 2 ]]; then
            cd "$i"
            #inside of $i now
            #do whatever you like
            pwd
            exit 0
        fi
    else
        echo "$i is NOT a directory"
    fi
done
```

I don't know if it is the best way to accomplish what you want.

Usage:

```
alex@MaD-pc:~$ ls
a                  Desktop    Downloads  gsettings_source  nitroshare  Qt             Templates  Wallch.DEB.Build
annoying_file.txt  Documents  Dropbox    Music             Pictures    second_dir.sh  Videos
alex@MaD-pc:~$ ./second_dir.sh 
Checking a
a is a directory
Checking annoying_file.txt
annoying_file.txt is NOT a directory
Checking Desktop
Desktop is a directory
/home/alex/Desktop
alex@MaD-pc:~$
```

The script will just `cd` on the 2nd directory that it will find. Just keep in mind that this will not work for hidden directories.

Answer (score 1):

I have written some script for you but this is not a complete answer to your question but I am sure it will help you though. I can list your first directory with my command.

```
ls | head -n 1 |awk '{print $1 }'
```

I am not sure how to change to directory then. I have taken your example.

```
jai@frank-Jai:~/sandbox$ ls | head -n 1 |awk '{print $1 }'
dir1
jai@frank-Jai:~/sandbox$ ls | head -n 2 |awk '{print $1 }'
dir1
dir2
jai@frank-Jai:~/sandbox$
```

we can list as many directories as we want.

Comment: @Oli , how to cd to the output that script which can list directories ?

Comment: yes, this is not complete, but close to what I want. "cd" remains.

Comment: yes I am thinking , you also try . :)

Comment: how do I print only the second or the third directory (or any other  I want to)?

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is [often precarious](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Increase or decrease the value of the head and that will change the number of dir output.

Comment: @EliahKagan but there is nothing I have mentioned to display the attributes of the files and folders.

Comment: @rajagenupula What happens if the directory contains files with spaces in their names? (That issue is not specific to parsing from `ls`, but often arises since ls formats output for viewing.) What about weird characters, like carriage returns? What if this is run by itself (as it appears the OP intends) and not as part of a script, the the user has customized the `ls` bash alias (which is a much more commonly customized alias than almost any other command)? I don't think it's absolutely wrong to parse the output of `ls`, but it should usually be reserved for applications extending `ls`.

Comment: @EliahKagan Hmm ok .

Answer (score 1):

I am slightly unsure as to what you want really, but I interpret your question as wanting a 'one-liner' that captures a list of directories in `$HOME`, for example, and then enables you to cd to the first or second directory in that list, or any of them for that matter.

This I think is possible if you place all the directories in an *array* and then you could cd to any directory in that array, by using, for example, `cd "${cdarray[1]}"`, which would actually take you to the *second* directory in the list, because Bash arrays always start at 0, so index 0 in the array is actually the first directory.

Here's the one-liner I created that you can use; modify it to suit your purposes. I exclude directories from the list that are actually symbolic links ( `[[ ! -L "$d" ]]` ). You can remove this test if you need to include them and just keep the test for the directory.

This is an example for the `$HOME` directory, and I have added `$HOME` to the command, so the paths are now absolute, so you will be able to later run `cd "${cdarray[1]}"` as a separate command from any location and it will work. If you create it for another directory, just specify that absolute path instead of `$HOME` in the command below, unless of course you want it to work only relative to the directory in which it was created.

```
cdarray=(); for d in *; do [[ ! -L "$HOME/$d" && -d "$HOME/$d" ]] && cdarray+=("$HOME/$d"); done; cd "${cdarray[1]}"
```

Now, any directories with spaces in their names will be handled successfully.

The indexed array is declared, and then if the found item is a directory and not a symlink, it is added to the array and then after the semi-colon we cd to the directory we want, e.g. `cd "${cdarray[1]}"`.

You could add `|| exit 1` at the end if you used this in a script, but I didn't add that above as it would close the interactive terminal if the cd command failed.